# Compile error with x:Bind in ConverterParameter (UWP) - VS 2017

Tags: compiler-errors, converters, datatemplate, uwp-xaml, xbind

Ok, I basically have two `ListView`s that load a collection which then needs to be presented with a certain style. To do that I use a `DataTemplate` which can be seen bellow.

In both `DataTemplate`'s I need to load an image and a text. The text works just fine, but in order for me to return the `URL` for the image, I have to get an `user id` and then an `image hash`, merge them together and return the `URL`.

So what I did, is I bind to the `user id`, and then I use a converter with a `ConverterParameter` value `x:Bind`ed to the `image hash`. The idea is that I take those two values and then the converter returns the final `string`. Both the `value` and the `parameter` are `strings` (`URI`'s).

While compiling (NOT on runtime) I get this `errors` that I can find anywhere an answer and I don't know what they mean. Event values cannot be broken across a line boundary...

[image: The compile error that I get!]

The `DataTemplate`s as they are:

```
xmlns:conv="using:App_Name.Converters"

    <conv:IconIdToUrlConverter x:Key="IconIdToUrlConverter"/>
    <conv:AvatarIdToUrlConverter x:Key="AvatarIdToUrlConverter"/>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="GuildsListDataTemplate" x:DataType="discweb:SocketGuild">
        <StackPanel Margin="0,5,0,0">
            <Ellipse Width="40" Height="40">
                <Ellipse.Fill>
                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="{x:Bind IconId, Mode=OneWay,Converter={StaticResource IconIdToUrlConverter},ConverterParameter={x:Bind Id,Mode=OneWay}}"/>
                </Ellipse.Fill>
            </Ellipse>
            <TextBlock TextAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords" Margin="0,2,0,0" Text="{x:Bind Name, Mode=OneWay}" Foreground="White" FontSize="12" />
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="GuildUsersListDataTemplate" x:DataType="discweb:SocketGuildUser">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,0,2,0">
            <Ellipse Width="10" Height="10">
                <Ellipse.Fill>
                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="{x:Bind AvatarId, Mode=OneWay,Converter={StaticResource AvatarIdToUrlConverter},ConverterParameter={x:Bind Discriminator,Mode=OneWay}}"/>
                </Ellipse.Fill>
            </Ellipse>
            <TextBlock TextAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords" Text="{x:Bind Username,Mode=OneWay}" Foreground="White" FontSize="10" />
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
```

And the `ListView` (One of the two, its same though):

```
<ListView ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
    ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalRailEnabled="False"
    ItemsSource="{x:Bind ChatViewModel.GuildUserList, Mode=OneWay}"
    SelectionMode="None" Grid.Column="1"
    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource GuildUsersListDataTemplate}"/>
```

**Note:** I am using the latest version of `Visual Studio 2017` that there currently is! Also, I have observed that when using `Binding` instead of `x:Bind` the compiler will not give any errors, but the code doesn't do what is intended to do simply because binding searches in the `Page`'s `DataContext` and not the one that I have specifically defined in my `DataTemplate`.

**EDIT (based on comment):**

Lines 33 and 59 are the two ImageBrushes in my DataTemplates, I have updated the code above with both of them. Both the ConverterParameter values return an int. The following code includes the converters class:

```
public class AvatarIdToUrlConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        BitmapImage s;
        if (value == null || parameter == null)
            s = new BitmapImage(new Uri("https://something.com/assets/dd4dbc0016779df1378e7812eabaa04d.png"));
        else
            s = new BitmapImage(new Uri(String.Format("https://something.com/avatars/" + parameter.ToString() + "/" + value.ToString() + ".png?size=128")));
        return s;

    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class IconIdToUrlConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        BitmapImage s;
        if (value == null || parameter == null)
            s = new BitmapImage(new Uri("https://something.com/assets/dd4dbc0016779df1378e7812eabaa04d.png"));
        else
            s = new BitmapImage(new Uri(String.Format("https://something.com/icons/" + parameter.ToString() + "/" + value.ToString() + ".png?size=128")));
        return s;

    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please just provide a [mcve] project? At least shows the converter which may possible lead the issue. And the what are the code lines in line 33 and 59 on the `ChatView.xaml`? I cannot reproduce your issue on my side currently.

Comment: Added code based on your comment. As I describe and in the original post, lines 33 and 59 are the two ImageBrushes in the Eclipses. Thank you!